# How remove interactive selection textfield in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm developping a Flutter App that needed to have a form. so i want to remove interactive selection from textfield, any suggetions ? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey i guess your looking for :

```
TextFormField(enableInteractiveSelection: false)
```